# permutation in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

```
class Solution {
public:
     vector<vector<int>> permute(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int> > result;
        vector<int> sofar;
        permutehelper(nums, sofar, result);
        return result;
    }
    
    void permutehelper(vector<int> &rest, vector<int> &sofar, vector<vector<int>> &ans){
                
        if(rest.size() == 0) {
            ans.push_back(sofar);
        }
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < rest.size(); i++){
                sofar.push_back(rest[i]);
                rest.erase(rest.begin() + i);
                permutehelper(rest, sofar, ans);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

How do I modify it to return all permutation, Currently it is giving only [[1,2,3]]. I know there are many solutions but I want to make it work using vectors sofar and rest.

Comment: Unless this is homework (or something similar) that requires you to do it entirely on your own, you may want to look up [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one `rest` vector (and only one `sofar` vector) because you are passing by reference. That means that when you remove an element from `rest`, it's gone. You never put it back, so it's gone forever. (In fact, you're removing elements from the vector passed as an argument to `permute`. Some would say that modifying the argument is poor interface design.)

You probably want to pass the parameter vectors by value (other than `ans`, which accumulates results and thus should be permanently modified). Of course, passing by value makes copies, which introduces an unnecessary quadratic complexity, but it will allow the algorithm to work as expected.

Comment: I was trying to implement a similar solution to that done in this lecture.  
https://youtu.be/uFJhEPrbycQ?t=2538

Comment: @unknown29: But in that lecture, the strings are passed by value, so there is a different string for each call, Moreover, since new strings are being created, the values of the strings are not being modified.